# equivalent to rspec's let in test::unit?

Tags: rspec, testunit

Anyone know of an equivalent in test::unit to rspec's :let and :let!?  E.g.

```
context "foo" do
  let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
  it "bar" do
    ...
  end
end
```

I'd love to use this convenient pattern when writing test::unit tests.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for `let!`:

```
def user
  @user ||= Factory(:user)
end
```

And for `let`, which does not cache between tests, you will need the same definition as above, and the following in either the `setup` or `teardown`:

```
@user = nil
```